# Changing the HTML of Apache's directory listing

Tags: apache-2.4

I'd love to globally customize the HTML and CSS of the default Apache2 directory listing. How could I do this? Is there a folder with the "skeleton" of this HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880975/how-to-style-directory-listings-with-apache-mod-autoindex-using-namewidth-html#55087425

Enable the [autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) mod, then add a stylesheet in the home (/) directory of your vhost like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# all other config
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    HeaderName header.html
    IndexStyleSheet /css.css
</IfModule>
# all other config
</VirtualHost>
```